# How do I group columns in MySQL and get rid of recurring ids?

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

MySQL

```
+-----+-----+
| id1 | id2 |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  1  |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  1  |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |
+-----+-----+
|  2  |  1  |
+-----+-----+
```

PHP

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT id1, COUNT(id2) AS count FROM table GROUP BY id1");
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
    echo 'id1: '.$b['id1'].' | count: '.$b['count'].'<br />';
}
```

Output:

```
id1: 1 | count: 3
id1: 2 | count: 1
```

But how do I remove recurring numbers in the column id2 for each id1? For example, the count where **id1 is 1** should be 2 instead of 3, because I want to count the **1 in id2** only once, and not twice.

So, the output should actually be:

```
id1: 1 | count: 2
id1: 2 | count: 1
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT id1, COUNT(DISTINCT id2) ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id1, COUNT(DISTINCT id2) AS count FROM table GROUP BY id1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  t.id1,COUNT(t.id2) AS count
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT id1,id2 FROM table) as t
GROUP BY 
  t.id1
```